# Unable to use custom HttpMessageNotReadableException error message in Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, exception

I'm currently trying to provide custom messages for exceptions, but ran into an issue with HttpMessageNotReadableException.

I have an ErrorDetails class:

```
public class ErrorDetails {
    private Date timestamp;
    private String message;
    private String details;



    public ErrorDetails(Date timestamp, String message, String details) {
        super();
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.message = message;
        this.details = details;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }
```

I also have a custom exception handler:

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
public class CustomizedExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
    @Override
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request){
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), "hello",request.getDescription(true));
        errorDetails.setMessage("Testing message");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails,HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }
}
```

But when i try to post a bad request, for example, with a field that should have a integer value I pass a string in the JSON it still returns the default error message of:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-03-12T00:15:14.210+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `int` from String \"lala\": not a valid Integer value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `int` from String \"lala\": not a valid Integer value\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 5, column: 17] (through reference chain: com.tdl.model.ToDoNote[\"priority\"])",
    "path": "/todos"
}
```

The JSON request:

```
{
    "name": "An workout",
    "dateToComplete": "Today",
    "description": "Sleep Day",
    "priority": "lala",
    "completed": false
}
```

The desired effect would just be the test message appearing instead of the long description.

I also get this in my Eclipse console:

> WARN 16508 --- [nio-5000-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `int` from String "lala": not a valid Integer value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `int` from String "lala": not a valid Integer value
>    at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 5, column: 17] (through reference chain: com.tdl.model.ToDoNote["priority"])]

I changed the status to NOT_ACCEPTABLE just to see more clearly if my custom error is returned.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**

Added ExceptionHandler for InvalidFormatException, but nothing changed. I still get the default error(exception) message same as before.

```
@ExceptionHandler(InvalidFormatException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleInvalidFormat(InvalidFormatException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request){
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), "hello",request.getDescription(true));
        errorDetails.setMessage("Testing message");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails,HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);

    }
```

Comment: try with `InvalidFormatException` exception

Comment: @Deadpool tried, but no change :/ (have both handleHttpMessageNotReadable and InvalidFormatException ExceptionHandlers now)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem is solved. I had my custom exception classes in a badly named package. It was called just exception. While it should have been com.app.exception where the whole project is.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error HttpMessageNotReadableException and I felt the need of customizing it. After a few trials, I ended up with a better and more readable format.
Step 1: Create a Custom Error Details class with the fields that you would want to expose to the client. Below is what I created.

```
public class ErrorDetails {
private final Date timestamp;
private final String message;
private final String details;

public ErrorDetails(Date timestamp, String message, String details) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.message = message;
    this.details=details;

}
```

// getters not included for brevity

Step 2: Create a class that will extend the ResponseEntityHandler which has the exceptions that can be overridden. Here, override the handleHttpMessageNotReadbale method, and then in the method have an implementation of your own custom error handler.

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(
        HttpMessageNotReadableException ex,
        HttpHeaders headers,
        HttpStatus status,
        WebRequest request) {
    ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), ex.getMessage(),request.getDescription(false));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

}

Step 3: Run your POST or PUT method with the wrong input fields and check the result. For instance, gender is an enum class with only FEMALE and MALE.

```
{
"firstName":"Dell",
"lastName":"HP",
"birthYear":"2000-02-12",
"email":"dell@gmail.com",
"gender":"BOY"
```

}

The response is like below:

{
"timestamp": "2022-06-06T08:08:53.906+00:00",
"message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.io.clinic.utils.Gender` from String "BOY": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [FEMALE, MALE]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.io.clinic.utils.Gender` from String "BOY": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: [FEMALE, MALE]\n at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 6, column: 14] (through reference chain: com.io.clinic.payloadDTO.PatientDTO["gender"])",
"details": "uri=/api/v1/patients"
}
I was satisfied with having the message in that state for debugging but you can also customize the message response in the overridden method.